# Installing custom SSL certificate in Node (UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, https

I'm trying to access an API, but I'm getting the following error:

```
{ FetchError: request to https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/api/GetMarkets failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (.../node_modules/node-fetch/index.js:133:11)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:159:13)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:389:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:159:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:152:19)
  name: 'FetchError',
  message: 'request to https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/api/GetMarkets failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate',
  type: 'system',
  errno: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE',
  code: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE' }
```

I tried using `ssl-root-cas` and I tried manually adding a certificate using `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS`. Neither of these worked.

The API is for a cryptocurrency exchange. I can connect to it using Chrome. I used a few SSL scanners and I got "This server's certificate chain is incomplete." Here's the results for one of the scanners: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.cryptopia.co.nz

After a bit of Googling, it looks like the error is caused by Node not downloading the intermediate certificate. Chrome downloaded it, so Chrome worked fine. I used Chrome to download the certificate as a `.cer` file, converted it to a `.pem` file using OpenSSL, then used Node's `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` to load it, but it didn't do anything.

How can I fix this issue?

I cannot make changes to the server. I contacted Cryptopia, but it'll probably take them weeks to respond. And obviously, I'm not going to disable strict SSL since I'm dealing with money.

Comment: Anyone know why NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS has no effect??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the whole CA chain to your application, i.e. both the missing intermediate CA certificate(s) and the root certificate:

```
options=require('url').parse('https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/api/GetMarkets');
options.ca = require('fs').readFileSync('myca.pem');
require('https').get(options, (r) => { 
   console.log(r.headers) 
});
```

`myca.pem` is here the concatenation of the PEM representation for the certificates of the intermediate "COMODO RSA Extended Validation Secure Server CA" and the root "COMODO RSA Certification Authority". I've provided it as pastebin [here](https://pastebin.com/wYyf7hW3).