# Perl LWP::Simple::get($url) does not work for some urls

Tags: perl

I am using LWP::Simple::get($url) library to access data from web pages. The problem is that the get function is not working for the below url.
Below is the code snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use LWP::Simple;
use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;

my $url = "https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/api/GetCurrencies";

my $json = get( $url);
die "Could not get $url!" unless defined $json;

my $decoded_json = decode_json($json);
print Dumper($decoded_json);
```

After running this code it gives the below error:

> *Could not get https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/api/GetCurrencies!*

When I replace the url with : `$url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/"` it works fine.
Please can you tell me what is the root cause and how I can fix it.
Also the url mentioned in the code snippet worked once and now suddenly it does not work.

Comment: If you replace `get()` with [`getprint()`](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/libwww-perl-6.31/lib/LWP/Simple.pm#getprint) then it gives `500 Can't connect to www.cryptopia.co.nz:443 (certificate verify failed) <URL:https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/api/GetCurrencies>`. It's an HTTP**S** issue. Probably they changed their policy and now only let you access the page with a valid certificate.

Comment: Thank You "PerlDuck" for your answer.When i replace get() with getprint(), it gives me the below error:    `500 Can't connect to www.cryptopia.co.nz:443 (Bad file descriptor) <URL:https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/api/GetCurrencies>
JSON text must be an object or array (but found number, string, true, false or null, use allow_nonref to allow this) .`                                      
 How can I still access this page with valid certifcate?

Comment: `get` and `getprint` behave differently. `get` either returns the content (success) or `undef` (error). If you get `undef` then you don't know why. `getprint` on the other hand _prints_ the content _or_ the error cause. It returns the HTTP code (such as `200` or `500`), not the content itself. So you cannot simply replace `get` with `getprint`. I just did it to see _why_ `get` fails. You get the JSON error because `decode_json` tried to interpret the `500` (which of course fails).

Comment: Thank You for the explanation. Please can you tell me is there any  way in which i can still access this page?And how do I get a valid certificate?

Comment: I'm curious why you want to access a cryptocurrency page that is no longer secure.  You can't trust that page!

Answer (score 5):

This is essentially the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48040682/installing-custom-ssl-certificate-in-node-unable-to-verify-leaf-signature), only for Perl LWP instead of NodeJS.

The problem is that the target site has a broken setup and is missing an intermediate certificate. This can be seen from the [SSLabs report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.cryptopia.co.nz):

> This server's certificate chain is incomplete. Grade capped to B.

To work around this you have two secure and one insecure option. The insecure but, unfortunately, often proposed option is to disable all certificate validation. **Don't do this** because it makes your application vulnerable against man-in-the-middle attacks.

The next option is to have your own trust store which includes all necessary certificates, i.e. both the root CA and also the missing intermediate CA:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use IO::Socket::SSL;
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->ssl_opts(
    SSL_ca_file => 'myca.pem', 
    # disable OCSP stapling since it results in problems with this site
    SSL_ocsp_mode => SSL_OCSP_NO_STAPLE
);
my $resp = $ua->get('https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/api/GetCurrencies');
print $resp->decoded_content;
```

`myca.pem` is in this case the concatenation of the PEM representation for the certificates of the intermediate "COMODO RSA Extended Validation Secure Server CA" and the root "COMODO RSA Certification Authority". I've provided it at Pastebin, [here](https://pastebin.com/wYyf7hW3).

The third option is to trust this specific leaf certificate only. When used this will trust a server using this certificate, no matter if the certificate is expired, revoked, the hostname does not match the URL or (as in this case) the trust chain cannot be built because of a missing intermediate certificate:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use IO::Socket::SSL;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->ssl_opts(
    SSL_fingerprint => 'sha256$70bca153ac950b8fa92d20f04dceca929852c42dc1d51bdc3c290df256ae05d3',
    SSL_ocsp_mode => SSL_OCSP_NO_STAPLE,
);
my $resp = $ua->get('https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/api/GetCurrencies');
print $resp->decoded_content;
```

The fingerprint you see here is the one you can also see in the browser when looking at the certificate.